# how to customize names of legend labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis

I have the following code:

```
p <- ggplot() + coord_fixed() + xlab("") + ylab("")

base_world <- p + geom_polygon(data=world_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
                                         colour="green", fill="whitesmoke") +
                      geom_point(data = as.data.frame(coordinates(busxy)), size = 1,
                                        mapping = aes(x = busxy@coords[,1], y = busxy@coords[,2],
                                                      color = busxy$color)) +
                      labs(title = "Cities\n", color = "States\n") +
                      scale_color_manual(labels = col2state$s, values = col2state$c)
```

It prints this:
[image]

The problem is the colors on map doesn't correspond with those in legend.
When I delete `scale_color_manual(labels = col2state$s, values = col2state$c)` from the plot it's all right but 'States' have names of colors from the data.

My question is: How to leave labels names like in the image but also assign proper colors to those labels as in the map?

In `col2state$c` are 29 color names (like #29A934)
In `col2state$s` are 29 state labels like in legend.
Data frame `busxy` contains 144k records with 29 unique values of states.

Data is from:
`library(maps)`

`world_map <- map_data("world")`

`busxy <- data.frame(x=bus[[1]]$latitude, y=bus[[1]]$longitude, city=bus[[1]]$city, state=bus[[1]]$state)`

`bus <- llply(as.list(jfile5), function(x) jsonlite::stream_in(file(x), pagesize = 10000))`
and `jfile5` is the path to json file contains all data.

Comment: we don't have access to busxy..

Comment: I've updated...

Answer (score 1):

`scale_color_manual` can do without the `labels` parameter. A way to solve this is `scale_color_manual(values = my_colors)` where `my_colors` is the mapping of countries to their color, organized in a named character vector, e.g. `c(AZ = "blue", NV = "red", ...)`

An example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y = 2:4, f = as.factor(1:3))
my_colors <- c('1'= "blue", '2' = "red", '3' = "yellow")
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = f)) + scale_color_manual(values = my_colors)
```

Comment: My colors are on second layer (geom_points). The first layer (geom_polygon) is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the columns, save vectors of the unique values for color and for state labels. Ensure the vectors are ordered to match.

```
vec_c <- unique(col2state$c)
vec_s <- unique(col2state$s) #may need to re-order, or opt to manually create vector
scale_color_manual(labels = vec_c, values = vec_s)
```